# Can't run ruby script with required tumblr_client

Tags: ruby, tumblr

Can't run ruby script with required tumblr_client. Installed gem 'tumblr_client', but I got an error:

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:153:in `new': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:153:in `memoized'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:234:in `<class:ProxyOptions>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:216:in `<module:Faraday>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/options.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:80:in `block in require_libs'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:79:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:79:in `require_libs'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:240:in `<module:Faraday>'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tumblr_client-0.8.5/lib/tumblr/connection.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tumblr_client-0.8.5/lib/tumblr/client.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tumblr_client-0.8.5/lib/tumblr_client.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:160:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:160:in `rescue in require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:149:in `require'
        from 1.rb:2:in `<main>'
<internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- tumblr_client (LoadError)
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from 1.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Script source code:

```
require 'tumblr_client'
require 'json'

client = Tumblr::Client.new({
  :consumer_key => 'bla-bla',
  :consumer_secret => 'bla-bla',
  :oauth_token => 'bla-bla',
  :oauth_token_secret => 'bla-bla'
})

res = client.queue("dystopia-arts-girls.tumblr.com", {:limit => 20, :offset => 0})

File.open('result.json', 'w'){ |file| file.write res.to_json }
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't run `gem install tumblr_client`.  It's telling you the gem isn't found in the `require` statement.

Comment: I run `gem install tumblr_client`. Really. I even tried to put it in folder with script and rewrite all pathes in gem to relative. It doesn't want to work

Comment: Do you have multiple ruby installations?  Are you sure the gem is installed for the ruby you're trying to run this with?

Comment: Yes, i checked that one and it even sees the gem. But why does it bump into `tumblr_client-0.8.5/lib/tumblr/connection.rb` I dont know

Comment: Something wrong with 'faraday'. I will try to update it

Answer (score 1):

The trouble was in 'faraday' and version of 'tumblr_client'
How I did repair it:

```
> gem install specific_install
> gem specific_install https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client
```

Also I uninstall old versions of `faraday` and `faraday_middleware`